# issues with wp_enqueue_script in my plugin

Tags: plugins, wp-enqueue-script

So I am working on a plugin and am trying to trigger a js file whenever a post is saved. I have been reading up on this all morning and cannot seem to find why this is not working. Any advice? If I were to paste the js code directly into the plugin it seems to work... I have double checked the path to the js and still no response.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'plugin_admin_init' );
function plugin_admin_init() {  
    wp_register_script( 'qtool-insert-v2', plugins_url() . '/buildStatus2/' . 'qtool-insert-v2.js' );
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'qtool-insert-v2' );
}
```

Here is the qtool-insert-v2.js - very simple redirect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
//-->
alert("HELLO");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hook into admin_enqueue_scripts with your add_my_script function.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts

Example:

```
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('qtool-insert-v2');
}add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
```

Comment: ahh okay thanks for that advice. I am now successfully seeing it in the source. Although their is no redirect or popup happening...

also, it looks like this script now loads on every admin page... any way I can only have it triggered on that save_post hook?

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://....../plugins/buildStatus2/qtool-insert.js?ver=3.3.2'></script>

Comment: looks like I don't need the <script> tags... still need to figure out a way to only have this trigger on a save post tho

Comment: You can only trigger the admin_enqueue_scripts on certain admin pages, see the link above (http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts#Example:_Target_a_Specific_Admin_Page)

Comment: @Greg Are you trying to run JS on a save post PHP action or a save click event?

Comment: @BrianFegter on a save post action. Whenever a post is published or updated.